# How does Imgur create encrypted file names to all the images it hosts?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imgur

I was planning on hosting images on a server and wanted to use the same sort of file naming encryption mechanism. Is it just a hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes.

```
$filename = md5($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].rand(50000000, 900000000000)).$ext;
```

Comment: Really? `md5` _and_ `sha1`? What you want to achieve with this?

Comment: as much as possible unique hash. However it'S not required and I should remove it.

Comment: This will cause collisions at some point. Best is to hash the internal primary key value identifying the resource, with some salting so that it's obviously not `sha(1)`, `sha(2)`, etc...

Comment: @Marc B  would it be too much to ask for an example? Thanks

Comment: @jini: assuming the image's id is in `$id`, `$hashed_id = sha1('some secret text to salt the id' . $id . 'some other secret salt text');`

Comment: @Marc: problem is that 'some secret text to salt the id' is always the same and therefore it won't help.

Comment: @genesis: doesn't have to be a cryptographically secure hash, just something so that the generated hash isn't going to be in any rainbow table. sha('1') is easy to get from any trivial checker. `sha1('some secret text1other secret text')` won't be.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a hash. If you have characters a-zA-Z0-9 and choose a hash only 6 characters long, you get 61,474,519 possible unique filenames. I doubt you'll run out =) use the mt_rand function for best results.

Comment: I think you mean that there are 56,800,235,584 possible unique 6-letter filenames, much more than what you quote. That's 62^6 possibilities with letters A-Za-z0-9.